# What is the fundamental error in my reasoning?

Tags: exponentiation

What is fundamentally wrong in writing $(-a)^{1/2}$ as $((-a)^{2})^{1/4}$ when $a$ is positive and thus equating it to $a^{1/2}$?

Edit:
I'm basically asking if there is anything wrong with this operation like multiplying $1$ and $2$ with $0$ and equating it to "prove" that $1=2$.

Comment: How can you write $-a$ as $(-a)^2$? This question is not clear.

Comment: $\sqrt{-a}$ is not defined for $a>0$, at least not within the real numbers.

Comment: @trebor sorry, i have edited the question.

Comment: @peter im not restricting myself to real numbers.

Comment: On complex numbers the usual rules don't hold.

Comment: Basically the problem is that many of the usual rules for exponentials and logarithms that are true over positive real numbers are no longer true over the complex numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When defining $a^{m/n}$ for $a > 0$, $m, n \in \Bbb N_{\ge 1},$ it is an exercise to verify that the following things hold:
$$a^{m/n} = (a^m)^{1/n} = (a^{1/n})^m = a^{m'/n'}$$
for any $m', n'\in \Bbb N_{\ge 1}$ such that $m'n = mn'$.

---

The point I want to make is that in a manipulation like $$a^{1/2} = a^{2/4} = (a^{2})^{1/4},$$
each equality has to be justified and does not just follow on its own.

It is to be checked that the usual manipulation of rational numbers goes through and that everything works the way you would desire to.

---

When you have $a < 0$, the things just don't hold anymore even if you involve complex numbers.